# Master page <div> change to another <div>

Tags: c#, asp.net

now I doing a website that having master page in asp.net with C#. In the login area I had create in master page with  element. But after that I login, I want to change the login layout to another  with different content. May I know how do I do it?

Comment: what did you try, show some code

Comment: I think you should clear your master page concepts first, then you wont need to ask this, every thing can be redefined in the contents.

Comment: Keep the login and the other content in two different panel with ID, check for logged in and switch the panels.

Comment: dont use master page for login page

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we don't use MasterPages for modules such as login. Because many a times, the rest of the website has a different layout (with menus, headers, footers, etc.).

The best way to do this is create your Login page seperately (without any master page). If you want to use masterpage for Login, then perhaps you can create another master page for a different layout.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new page, it asks to include the Master Page. If you don't want that common html css of Master Page, then don't include it.

If you have already created page and want to remove Master Page content, then simply remove from Page Header as shown below:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.master"...
```

to

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ..
```

Also you can create multiple Master Page, which you can inherit for different pages.

Answer (score 0):

In your master page, you have to define BOTH the login area, and the different layout content inside a server side div. Depending whether or not the user is logged in, you can then hide/show each div.

for example:

divLogin.Visible = !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
divOtherStuff.Visible = User.IdentityIsAuthenticated;